# Remove linebreaks from file

Tags: python, ruby, bash, text-processing

I have a text file of the following format:

```
Run#1 Step#1 > Connecting to server
Run#1 Step#2 > Connected OK
Run#1 Step#3 > Sending request: {
    "path": "/testpage",
    "time": "2015-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"
}
Run#1 Step#4 > Request sent OK
```

What I need to do is to process this file. It would be easier if each step was printed on a separate line:

```
Run#1 Step#1 > Connecting to server
Run#1 Step#2 > Connected OK
Run#1 Step#3 > Sending request: { "path": "/testpage", "time": "2015-06-07T00:00:00.000Z" }
Run#1 Step#4 > Request sent OK
```

How can I do this (either in bash or ruby/python/... script) ?

Comment: why are some  lines joined?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what do you mean? which lines are joined?

Comment: `Run#1 Step#3 > Sending request: { "path": "/testpage", "time": "2015-06-07T00:00:00.000Z" }`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this is what I want to get from initial file

Comment: so you want lines not starting with `Run#1` to be combined into a single line added to the previous line starting with `Run#1`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Comment: Just a simple one liner: '\nRun'.join("".join(file.readlines()).replace('\n', '').split('Run')). Maybe need to be little tweaked but works.

Comment: @xaxa, did you run the  python code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've written my own already in Ruby. I was hoping josifoski's answer would work, but seems like it won't on Mac

Comment: @xaxa. you should remove the python tag if you don't want a python solution

Comment: I wanted any solution when I asked the question, it just happened that I've written it in ruby first. But if solution in pure bash would work that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) split("\n")
2) replace("Run#", "\nRun#")
3) delete first line ("\n")

Comment: text = text.replace("\n", " ").replace("Run#","\nRun#").replace("  "," ")

Answer (score 1):

gnu sed solution

```
cat file | sed ':a; N; $! ba; s/\n//g; s/Run#/\nRun#/g;' | sed '1d;' > outputfile
```

Comment: This is great idea, but it doesn't work unfortunately. File is not changed at all. I don't understand why...

Comment: now it will work,  previosly was only to console, now have redirection to outputfile (name it like you want)

Comment: No, I did redirection to file. Probably line-endings are not correct (windows style)?

Comment: Actually I use Mac, probably this is the problem but it still does nothing http://take.ms/kaTgz

Comment: sed --version gnu sed is best! for mac... hm, with gnused no problems, here add ; before ending sed like \nRun#/g;'

Comment: This will keep all the spaces from the start of the lines

Comment: No `--version` option supported. From `man sed` looks like it's not GNU's. I tried your last edit, but same result unfortunately....

Comment: here is screenshot my side http://i.imgur.com/QfCsCCO.png of course installing gnu sed will be wise idea :)

Answer (score 1):

using python group the lines based on lines starting with `Run#` and join any sections of lines that don't start with Run# to the previous Run# line regardless of the content, it will also replace the original file and you don't need to read the whole file into memory:

```
from itertools import groupby
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("file.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".",delete=False) as  out:
    grouped = groupby(f, key=lambda x: not x.startswith("Run#"))
    for k, v in grouped:
        if not k:
            v, nxt = "".join(v), next(grouped, "  ")[1]
            out.write("{}{}\n".format(v.rstrip(), "".join(map(str.strip, nxt))))
        else:
            out.writelines(v)

move(out.name,"file.txt")
```

Output:

```
Run#1 Step#1 > Connecting to server
Run#1 Step#2 > Connected OK
Run#1 Step#3 > Sending request: {"path": "/testpage","time": "2015-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"}
Run#1 Step#4 > Request sent OK
```

Answer (score -1):

If all your files looks exactly like this one you can solve your problem with this code

```
file=open(filename,"r+")

lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if (line.startswith("Run") and not "{" in line) or "}" in line:
        print(line,end='')
    else:
        print(line.replace("\n",""), end='')
```